# Having issue with my favorite button functionality in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an issue with my favorite button. I have connected it with real-time firebase and each time I press the favorite icon it changes the state in firebase either true or false. when I press the heart button it always shows me different output sometimes it becomes red or black without affecting the other and sometimes it changes the other ones too (red or black). I have tried a lot to solve this but I am unable to get a solution for it.

```dart
class Home_page extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<Home_page> createState() => _Home_pageState();
    }
    
    class _Home_pageState extends State<Home_page> {
      //late StreamSubscription _dailySpecialStream;
      var clr = Colors.grey;
      //var item;
    
      final List<String> _listItem = [
        'assets/audi3.png',
        'assets/audi.png',
        'assets/audi2.png',
        'assets/audi.png',
        'assets/audi2.png',
        'assets/audi3.png',
      ];
      var name;
      var auth1 = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      Data? c;
      late final Value;
      List<Data> dataList = [];
      List<dynamic> d = [];
      List<dynamic> favList = [];
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        print("object");
        super.initState();
        print(auth1);
        _activateListener();
      }
    
      void _activateListener() {
        final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    
        _database.child('user').get().then((snapshot) {
          dataList.clear();
          favList.clear();
          print("hello");
    
          Value = snapshot.value as Map;
          final datas = snapshot.children.forEach((element) {
            d.add(element.key);
          });
    
          for (var k in d) {
            //print("");
            print(Value[k]['imgUrl']);
            print((Value[k]['carName']).runtimeType);
            dataList.add(Data(
              Value[k]['carName'],
              Value[k]['price'],
              Value[k]["imgUrl"],
              k,
            ));
    
            if (auth1 != null) {
              print(k);
              print("auth1");
              print(auth1);
              DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .ref()
                  .child("user")
                  .child(k)
                  .child("fav")
                  .child(auth1!.uid)
                  .child("state");
    
              reference.get().then((s) {
                print(s.value);
                print("upp is vla");
                if (s.value != null) {
                  if (s.value == true) {
                    // print(s.value);
                    // print("true");
                    favList.add(true);
                    print(favList);
                  } else {
                    //print(s.value);
                    print("false1");
                    favList.add(false);
                    //print(favList);
                  }
                } else {
                  print("inelse");
                  favList.add(false);
                  print(favList);
                }
              });
            }
          }
    
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            setState(() {
              inspect(favList);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/top.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      search(context),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 80,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 40,
                        children: List.generate(
                            dataList.length, (index) => GridDesign(index)).toList(),
                      )),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      SizedBox GridDesign(int index) {
        return SizedBox(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 15.h,
                    width: 45.w,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 12, right: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        // border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey,style: BorderStyle.solid,width: 2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(dataList[index].url.toString()),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: -3,
                    right: 5,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 32,
                      width: 32,
                      child: Neumorphic(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          style: NeumorphicStyle(
                              //shape: NeumorphicShape.concave,
                              boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(
                                  BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                              color: Colors.white),
                          child: favList[index]
                              ? IconButton(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  
                                    if (auth1 != null) {
                                      print(auth1);
                                      print("it's not null");
                                      DatabaseReference favRef = FirebaseDatabase
                                          .instance
                                          .ref()
                                          .child("user")
                                          .child(
                                              dataList[index].uploadId.toString())
                                          .child("fav")
                                          .child(auth1!.uid)
                                          .child("state");
                                      favRef.set(false);
                                      setState(() {
                                        favFun();
                                      });
                                    }
    
                                    print("object");
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : IconButton(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  onPressed: () {
                               
    
    
                                    if (auth1 != null) {
                                      print("it's not null1");
                                      print(auth1);
                                      DatabaseReference favRef = FirebaseDatabase
                                          .instance
                                          .ref()
                                          .child("user")
                                          .child(
                                              dataList[index].uploadId.toString())
                                          .child("fav")
                                          .child(auth1!.uid)
                                          .child("state");
                                      favRef.set(true);
                                      setState(() {
                                        favFun();
                                      });
                                    }
    
                                    print("object");
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite,
                                  ))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 4,
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text(dataList[index].CarName.toString())),
              SizedBox(height: 2),
              Expanded(
                child: Text("R" + dataList[index].price.toString()),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 3),
              Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () =>
                    Get.to(DetailPage(dataList[index].Url, dataList[index].Price)),
                child: Text("Details"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: myColor),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void favFun() {
        final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
        _database.child('user').get().then((snapshot) {
          favList.clear();
    
          for (var k in d) {
            //print("");
    
            if (auth1 != null) {
              print(k);
              print("auth1");
              print(auth1);
              DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .ref()
                  .child("user")
                  .child(k)
                  .child("fav")
                  .child(auth1!.uid)
                  .child("state");
    
              reference.once().then((DatabaseEvent s) {
                print(s.snapshot.value);
                print("upp is vla");
                if (s.snapshot.value != null) {
                  if (s.snapshot.value == true) {
                    // print(s.value);
                    // print("true");
                    favList.add(true);
                    print(favList);
                  } else {
                    //print(s.value);
                    print("false1");
                    favList.add(false);
                    //print(favList);
                  }
                } else {
                  print("inelse");
                  favList.add(false);
                  print(favList);
                }
              });
            }
          }
    
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            setState(() {
              //inspect(favList);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

Have a look at the picture to get a better view

[image]

Comment: You shared quite a bit of code. When you step through this code in a debugger line by line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Inside favfun() the function at the bottom. Inside it snapshot.value is not returning the exact value of nodes that exists in real-time firebase https://imgur.com/a/kbOz3gk in the picture you can see that in the favlist at the second index it is giving me false but it is true in the realtime firebase for the 2nd node. https://imgur.com/xI5IUrg .Don't know sometimes it returns the correct value and the function works correctly for what it is called for.

Comment: That sounds like useful debugging information  Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to show this in a more readable format?